# Python: Downloading google search links, multiple pages /news search

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download links from a google search (in Python), I'm using beautiful soup to do this. `http://www.google.ca/search?q=QUERY_HERE` is the url that I get requests from. I want to get more links i.e from the 2nd/3rd pages.

How do I do this, and how may I search only using google news search?

Comment: Could you clarify what version of Python and Beautiful Soup your using?

Comment: Python3  and   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  is how I get this module in so i'm guessing version 4 ? Sorry im new to python

Comment: my guess was this was more of a google search links question and how the structure works...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly find out **Results per page** setting for you using the *search settings* option found in the bottom right corner of the [google.com](http://www.google.com) page.
or check the link below if it is still working

https://www.google.co.in/preferences?hl=en

Then in the query you can specify the **start** value

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hello&hl=en----------**start=70**--------.

So if **start = 0** you are on first page and then you can simply change the **start** value according to your **Results per page**.

Answer (score 0):

To search only using Google News you need to add `tbm=nws` to your url.
`https://www.google.com/search?q=coca+cola` --> `https://www.google.com/search?q=coca+cola&tbm=nws`

Here's how you can do it using `beautifulsoup`, `requests`, `urllib` libraries to scrape with actual pagination.

Code and example in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-News-with-Pagination-python-serpapi#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, urllib.parse

def paginate(url, previous_url=None):
    # Break from infinite recursion
    if url == previous_url: return

    headers = {
        "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

    # First page
    yield soup

    next_page_node = soup.select_one('a#pnnext')

    # Stop when there is no next page
    if next_page_node is None: return

    next_page_url = urllib.parse.urljoin('https://www.google.com/',
                                         next_page_node['href'])

    # Pages after the first one
    yield from paginate(next_page_url, url)


def scrape():
    pages = paginate(
        "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&q=coca+cola&tbm=nws")

    for soup in pages:
        print(f'Current page: {int(soup.select_one(".YyVfkd").text)}')
        print()

        for data in soup.findAll('div', class_='dbsr'):
            title = data.find('div', class_='JheGif nDgy9d').text
            link = data.a['href']

            print(f'Title: {title}')
            print(f'Link: {link}')
            print()

# part of the output:
'''
Results via beautifulsoup

Current page: 1
Title: A Post-Truth World: Why Ronaldo Did Not Move Coca-Cola Share Price
Link: https://www.forbes.com/sites/iese/2021/06/19/a-post-truth-world-why-ronaldo-did-not-move-coca-cola-share-price/

...

Current page: 22

Title: The Coca-Cola Co. unveils oat milk line
Link: https://www.foodbusinessnews.net/articles/18356-the-coca-cola-co-unveils-oat-milk-line
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=fus%20ro%20dah&gl=us&hl=en).

Code to integrate:

```py
# https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-python
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

def scrape():
  params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "coca cola",
    "tbm": "nws",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  }

  search = GoogleSearch(params)
  pages = search.pagination()

  for result in pages:
    print(f"Current page: {result['serpapi_pagination']['current']}")

    for news_result in result["news_results"]:
        print(f"Title: {news_result['title']}\nLink: {news_result['link']}\n")

# part of the output:
'''
Results from SerpApi

Current page: 1
Title: A Post-Truth World: Why Ronaldo Did Not Move Coca-Cola Share Price
Link: https://www.forbes.com/sites/iese/2021/06/19/a-post-truth-world-why-ronaldo-did-not-move-coca-cola-share-price/

...

Current page: 5
Title: Coca-Cola, Monster win appeal of $9.6 million verdict over ...
Link: https://www.reuters.com/legal/transactional/coca-cola-monster-win-appeal-96-million-verdict-over-hansens-rights-2021-06-18/
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.